# Receive Twilio sms on a device

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to receive SMS messages using Twilio on a mobile app? IP Messaging seems to be a more suitable option for sending/receiving messages, but we need SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can receive SMS messages sent to your Twilio number in a mobile app, but you would have to build yourself a web application to deal with the incoming messages and API requests.

Like the blog post on [how to send an SMS from an Android app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) you need to do all of your REST API requests from a web application as you shouldn't keep your Twilio credentials in the application.

Also, Twilio makes an HTTP request to a URL that you supply when you receive messages. So, what I'd recommend is that you build an endpoint that can receive those HTTP requests and then turn them into a push notification to your Android application. That way, your users will get a push notification when your Twilio number receives an SMS.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can send message from Twilio using its API. Twilio provides different ways to send message in different language. I have did it using java. It will be used in Android as well. I think they are providing SDK for Twilio Messages.

Let me know If you need any kind of details.
This might help you : https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html

Comment: Thanks. It's clear how to send, the problem is how to receive. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-messages-without-Responding: "When an SMS message is received by one of your Twilio numbers, Twilio makes an HTTP request to the SMS Request URL configured for that number".